# How to use bwareafilt matlab function with 3d matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, function, image-processing, matrix

I need to use bwareafilt function for 3d matrix "image" in matlab but that have an issue as it returns with an error saying that its input should be 2d matrix, how can I overcome that ??

I am working on CT lung images, In 2d version I used bwareafilt with no problems, but in 3d volume of CT I can't

```
y = ~bwareafilt(out > 1,1); % out is the segmented lung image, I need to remain the largest area in the image, which will be the lungs
z = imfill(~y,'holes');
mask = y.*z;
se2=strel('disk',10);
mask=imopen(mask,se2);
mask=imclose(mask,se2);
```

Comment: Ahmed: could you please share some more details about what you are trying to do with bwareafilt? IMO, area is inherently 2D, and you might be looking to extract small volumes, right? Could you share some code, on dummy data for example, showing what you want to do with bwareafilt? I'm curious to know what outcome you are expecting with 3D matrices.

Comment: I edited the question and added some info.

Comment: right, so when you say 'remain the largest', I believe the largest component is a 3d matrix, right? In that case, bwareafilt unfortunately won't work. You could try using a spherical structuring element to do morphology, (look at the 3d example here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html#examples) though.